# DB2 ODBC inconsistent connectivity

Tags: asp.net, database, db2, odbc

My ASP.net application uses ODBC(64 bit) to connect to DB2 Database(9.5.3). I am using 64 bit IBM DB2 Client 10.5. on Windows Server 2008 R2.
Connection pool is turned on.

It works fine(immediate connectivity) for most of the time, but occasionally too much time is consumed to establish connectivity. By too much time I mean to say 10 to 11 minutes. No error is reported. No issue with database, as it can be accessed from other servers at same timestamp.

All database request issued during this time via DB2 Client are kept on hold and then once connectivity is established, all are executed immediately.

When the issue is going on, I tried to connect to database through Windows server CMD and that too waits for around 10 mins. No error is reported. 
Network team says they dont see network traffic from Windows server to Database server when issue is going on. And no errors from network side. Which means DB2 client is not making connectivity request.

What could be causing delay in connectivity? This is not a consistent issue. It automatically resolves after around 10 mins. Is there any issue with DB2 driver ?  Was any resource withheld during that time? I am closing all connections properly.

Comment: I am using DB2CLIO.DLL (Version 10.05.500.107)

Comment: Cross-posted at http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/121515/db2-odbc-inconsistent-connectivity